# Sup in Woocommerce with comma for decimal

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I wrote the following code to change the position and appearance of the decimal places.

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'ts_woo_decimal_price', 10, 5 );
function ts_woo_decimal_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    $unit = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
    $decimal = sprintf( '%02d', ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 );
    return $unit . '<sup>' . $decimal . '</sup>';
}
```

The code works so far that the decimal places are superscript, but now I'm missing the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just add comma before  in last line, like this.

`return $unit . ',<sup>' . $decimal . '</sup>'`;